# I want to delete a record in my CSV file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv, delete-row

Should I just load it in an array delete the selected row and save it back in? Or is there a more efficient way?

Example:

> ddddd,aaaa,dddd,
> ffff fffff,ffff,
> ffff,ffff sssss,
> ssss,dddd,ffff

I need to load all of this in a array, find the line that I wish to delete and delete it. Then save it over the old file.

Comment: @plutonix I've only just gained the privileges to vote up.

Comment: you can always accept answers on your own questions - in fact you are the only one who can.  It would have gotten you upvote rights sooner too.  http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: I wasn't really aware of this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to delete a portion of a text file and automatically shift all of the remaining data up to fill its place.  The only way to do something like that is to rewrite the file.

The simplest solution, as you described, is to load the entire file into memory, make modifications to it in memory, and then overwrite the original file with the modified one from memory.  The down-side to that approach is that you must load the entire file in memory all at the same time.  That could be problematic if the file is particularly large.

If file-size is a concern, you will need to resort to some other method.  For instance, you could open two file streams--one to read the original file (source) and one to write out the modified file (target).  You could read one record at a time from the source stream and then only output it to the target stream if it is a record that you wish to keep.  When you are done, you could then delete the original file and then rename the target file to take its place.  It's more complicated, and a little slower, perhaps, but that way you never have more than one record loaded in memory at a time.

### Edit

Based on your comments below, here is a simple example of how to load a file into an array of strings (one string per line in the file) and then output the lines to the console:

```
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv")
For Each line As String In lines
    Console.WriteLine(line)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks once again Ste!

Comment: I'm having trouble generating a code for this, I'm on the verge of smashing something. I keep on forgetting simple code snippets...

Comment: What you trying to do and what part are you having trouble with?  It would probably be best to just mark this question as answered, though, and ask a new more specific question.

Comment: I need to delete some records within my CSV file.

Comment: Example:  
ddddd,aaaa,dddd,ffff
fffff,ffff,ffff,ffff
sssss,ssss,dddd,ffff

I need to load all of this in a array, find the line that I wish to delete and delete it. Then save it over the old file.

Comment: Right.  What I'm trying to say is, I gave a couple different options.  Which one are you attempting to implemnent?

Comment: Using the two streams, one for writing and the other for reading.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code that you've tried?  Which part are you having trouble with?  Loading?  Parsing?  Determining which line to skip?  Getting the new file path?  Writing to the new file?  Deleting the old file?  Renaming the new file?  All of the above?  You need to take one step at a time and be more specific.   If you do so, I promise you'll get much better responses from more people.  Please don't take this the wrong way.  I'm not trying to be rude or unhelpful.  On the contrary, I'm trying to give you pointers to help you to get the help you need.

Comment: I fully understand.I'm using streamreader>> using a do while (not line is nothing). The part that I need the help most on is storing the records temporarily in a array. Therefore, I can later on select the record(row) I wish to delete and save it back into a file using stream writer.

Comment: If you are going to store the entire thing in an array, then there's really no reason to use the `StreamReader` at all.  It would be much easier to just call `Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(myFilePath)`.  As you can see, that method returns an array for you (one element per line).

Comment: When I write it using console I receive "System.String[]"

Comment: That's because when you write an object to the console, it calls the `ToString` method on the object to get the string representation.  If the object does not override the `ToString` method, it will default to using the base `Object.ToString` method which simply outputs the name of the object's type.  In this case, it is a string array.  Arrays do not override the `ToString`, method, so when you call it, it just outputs the name of it's type ("System.String[]").  The brackets indicate that it is an array.

Comment: In order to output the contents of an array, you need to loop through each item in the array (e.g. `For Each line As String In Lines`) and output each item individually (e.g. `Console.WriteLine(line)`.

Comment: I've done this previously and that's when the "System.String[]" came to show.

Comment: No you didn't :)  I'll update my answer with a complete example which will work for you.

Comment: Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv")
        For Each line As String In lines
            Console.WriteLine(line.ToString)
        Next

Comment: I just tested that code that in your last comment and it worked correctly.  The only way that would output "System.String[]" would be if that was the actual contents of the csv file.

Comment: Yayyy, it writes all of the lines.

Comment: How would I approach it when deleting some of the rows?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to make it a `List(Of String)` rather than an array (e.g. `Dim lines As New List(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(...))`)  Then you can remove any item in the list at will.

Comment: Is their a code snippet for deleting or should I just enter a blank line and save it as that?

Comment: `lines.Remove(line)` or `lines.RemoveAt(index)`?